# how can i prevent a script from running while I'm launching the server?

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I have a script that queries a third party API when the script is called from within my sinatra application, but I do not want it to run when I am launching my Thin server. Is there a way to prevent my code from running until I call it directly? for instance, can I run a check to see if my server is running from within ruby/sinatra to prevent my code from running?

```
# the following code is inside a class and gets initialized when my server launch script is executed

authToken = ENV['EVERNOTE_AUTH_TOKEN']
evernoteHost = "www.evernote.com"
userStoreUrl = "https://#{evernoteHost}/edam/user"

userStoreTransport = Thrift::HTTPClientTransport.new(userStoreUrl)
userStoreProtocol = Thrift::BinaryProtocol.new(userStoreTransport)
userStore = Evernote::EDAM::UserStore::UserStore::Client.new(userStoreProtocol)
# this line of code executes on server start
noteStoreUrl = userStore.getNoteStoreUrl(authToken)
```

It appears that ruby does a syntax check when running each file, and my API is being called against my will on the last line, i want to write an if statement that makes it un-callable unless my server is already running

Comment: "Is there a way to prevent my code from running until I call it directly?" How is the code being called, if not directly? Your question seems to be missing a lot of crucial information. Please edit your question to include enough information (and, in particular, code) so that we can reproduce your problem.

Comment: @Jordan noted, and updated

Comment: It's still not clear how this code is being called "against your will." A "syntax check" wouldn't cause code to run unless there's code telling to to run—and I don't think any such "check" is happening. Either the code is executed or it's not. When you say the code above is "inside a class," what do you mean? Is it in a method? Where is the class?